# Microsoft Graph REST API beta: Get hosted content bytes

Tags: java, microsoft-graph-sdks

In the Microsoft Graph REST API beta documentation in section [Get chatMessageHostedContent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessagehostedcontent-get?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=java) there is the Java example for getting hosted content bytes for an image:

```
InputStream stream = graphClient
  .chats("19:2da4c29f6d7041eca70b638b43d45437@thread.v2")
  .messages("1615971548136") .hostedContents("aWQ9eF8wLXd1cy1kOS1lNTRmNjM1NWYxYmJkNGQ3ZTNmNGJhZmU4NTI5MTBmNix0eXBlPTEsdXJsPWh0dHBzOi8vdXMtYXBpLmFzbS5za3lwZS5jb20vdjEvb2JqZWN0cy8wLXd1cy1kOS1lNTRmNjM1NWYxYmJkNGQ3ZTNmNGJhZmU4NTI5MTBmNi92aWV3cy9pbWdv")
  .content()
  .buildRequest()
  .get();
```

... but using the latest tag `microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java` ([0.9.0-20210615.3](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java/tree/0.9.0-20210615.3)) this example doesn't work as `content` method in `ChatMessageHostedContentRequestBuilder` cannot be resolved.

With that in mind my question is what is official way of downloading hosted content bytes.

Related question with some more details is also present on [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-beta-sdk-java/issues/128).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like this will be fixed in the future - but for the time being this workaround should do it:

```
String valueUrl = graphClient
.chats(chatId)
.messages(messageId)
.hostedContents(hostedContentId)
.getRequestUrlWithAdditionalSegment("$value");

InputStream stream = new CustomRequestBuilder<>(valueUrl, graphClient, null, InputStream.class).buildRequest().get();
```